# Beeline writes to STDERR but not to STDOUT

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, beeline

I am running the Beeline client on a linux server using the following command line.

The whole command is on a single line. It works fine and writes STDERR to $errFile successfully. But it fails to write STDOUT  to the file specified as $outputFile.

```
nohup beeline -u "jdbc:$jdbcUrl " -f $QueryFile </dev/null 1> $outputFile 2> $errFile &
```

The $errFile says 9 rows are returned for the query.
If I don't redirect the STDOUT, it dumps the 9 rows to terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
nohup beeline -u "jdbc:$jdbcUrl" -f $QueryFile </dev/null 2> $errFile >> $outputFile &
```

Comment: I tried it, but the issue is still there. As before, it is not writing to STDOUT while STDERR is fine.

Comment: Moderators, please close this question. I suspect it may be related to OS and I will try to post it in a OS related forum

Answer (score 0):

nohup command should redirect the output to nohup.out when STDOUT is not redirected.

nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.

Refer: [Nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Use)